# checking input hex msg's 3rd position --> in C prog

Tags: c

I need idea about my program "checking input hex msg's 3rd position"

1. the program will take an input message in hex value. e.g. 0x0123456789abcdef
2. program will check the 3rd position of input message i.e. 0
3. now program will take another input message in hex value. e.g. 0x123456789abcdef0

   - here program will check the 3rd position of input message i.e. 1
4. program will take another input message in hex value. e.g. x23456789abcdef10

   - here program will check the 3rd position of input message i.e. 2
5. program will take another input message in hex value. e.g. 0x3456789abcdef210

   - here program will check the 3rd position of input message i.e. 3

The process must be done 18 times.

Every time program will check the 3rd position of the input message. If the 3rd position of input message is an increment e.g. 1st input message's 3rd position is 0, 2nd input message's 3rd position is 1, 3rd input message's 3rd position is 2 and so on. Then program will continue with tacking input messages and check the 3rd position of input message.

If the 3rd position of input message is not increment e.g. 3rd input message's 3rd position is NOT 2 then program will send a message and stop.

I tried to write the program but it does not work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {    
    char a[18], b[18], c[18], d[18],e[18], f[18], g[18], h[18];
    char value;
    char hexmsg[18], nextmsg[18]; /// ={0x0123456789abcdef};

    printf(" write the hexmsg \n");

    gets(hexmsg);

    printf(" \n The Alive Counter is %c \n",hexmsg[2]);
    printf(" write the first message \n");

    gets(nextmsg);

    value= value+hexmsg[2];

    int i;
    i=value;

    while(i<18){    
        if(i==nextmsg[2]){    
            printf("OK");       
            printf(" write the nextmsg \n");

            gets(nextmsg);

            i++;
        }else{
            printf("NOT OK");

            break; // --> break must to stop the while Loop
        }

    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "it does not work". That doesn't tell us much about the behaviour of your program. Please expand.

Comment: This program has more wrong lines than the right ones. Even considering the empty ones.

Answer (score 0):

You mainly have four problems.

1. "0x0123456789abcdef" need 19 rooms. E.g char hexmsg[19];
2. Numbers and letters are different. E.g 0 != '0'
3. `char value;`... `value= value+hexmsg[2];` : using an uninitialized variable
4. `gets` is obsoleted. You should not use it. There is a danger of entering more than the buffer size.

For example, do as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void){
    //input format : 0x0123456789abcdef
    char hexmsg[17];// omit 0x, 16 hexdigit chars + 1 for NUL
    char line[96], ch;

    for(int i = 0; i < 18; ++i){//do 18 times
        printf("write the hexmsg>");fflush(stdout);
        fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);//Make room for input acceptance
        if(1 != sscanf(line, "0%*1[xX]%16[0-9A-Fa-f] %c", hexmsg, &ch)){
            printf("invalid input\n");
            --i;//cancel this turn
            continue;
        }
        ch = tolower(*hexmsg);//3rd position of input
        if(ch == "0123456789abcdef"[i % 16]){//check hexdigit : 0..9a..f01
            puts("OK");
        } else {
            puts("NOT OK");
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```